# How do I to pass value my ViewBag for View in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, viewbag

I have a method which convert my html in a string for export to PDF
only I need convert my html (View) to a string in order to export to PDF

Code:

```
 public string RenderViewToString(Controller controller, string viewName, object viewData)
    {
        var renderedView = new StringBuilder();
        using (var responseWriter = new StringWriter(renderedView))
        {
            var fakeResponse = new HttpResponse(responseWriter);
            var fakeContext = new HttpContext(HttpContext.Current.Request, fakeResponse);
            var fakeControllerContext = new ControllerContext(new HttpContextWrapper(fakeContext), controller.ControllerContext.RouteData, controller.ControllerContext.Controller);

            var oldContext = HttpContext.Current;
            HttpContext.Current = fakeContext;

            using (var viewPage = new ViewPage())
            {
                var html = new HtmlHelper(CreateViewContext(responseWriter, fakeControllerContext), viewPage);

                html.RenderPartial(viewName, viewData);
                HttpContext.Current = oldContext;
            }
        }

        return renderedView.ToString();
    }
```

But the value is not going to view my ViewBag:

```
   ViewBag.Email = usuario.strUsuarioEmail;
   ViewBag.Nome = usuario.strUsuarioNome;
```

Code Export PDF:

```
      public ActionResult EventoVisualizarPDF()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UrlAPI"]);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var id = Session["intCodigoGrupoUsuario"];
        var intUsuarioId = Session["intUsuarioId"];
        string url = "";

        url = "api/usuario/GetBuscaUsuario/" + intUsuarioId;

        HttpResponseMessage resposta = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        if (resposta.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var usuario = resposta.Content.ReadAsAsync<Usuario>().Result;
            ViewBag.Email = usuario.strUsuarioEmail;
            ViewBag.Nome = usuario.strUsuarioNome;
        }

        url = "api/evento/GetEventoByUsuario/" + id;

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var eventos = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Evento>>().Result;

            return this.ViewPdf("Customer report", "RelatorioEventoPDF", eventos.OrderBy(m => m.strEventoCodigo));

        }
        else
        {
            string msg = response.IsSuccessStatusCode.ToString();
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
    }
```

how do to retrieve the value from my ViewBag in view?

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with [blob storage in Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs-20/#what-is), you can think of the `ViewBag` as the same abstract type of data store.

I'm assuming that you want to output these values so they can be consumed by your View -> PDF conversion method, so all you need on your view is :

```
<label id="vbEmail">@ViewBag.Email</label>

<label id="vbNome">@ViewBag.Nome</label>
```

That will output the values you've set in the controller as HTML.